# How to set a type for a React Compnent being passed in as a prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have the following code where I'm rendering a component or redirecting the user based on auth state. I'm having trouble understanding what the component prop type should be set to in the interface I've declared:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuthState } from '../../../context/authenticationContext';

interface AppProps {
    path: string,
    isPrivate: boolean,
}

const AppRoutes = ({ component: Component, path, isPrivate, ...rest }: AppProps) => {
    const authDetails = useAuthState();
    ...
    return (
        <Route
            path={path}
            render={props => (isPrivate && !authDetails.user) ? (
                <Redirect
                    to={{ pathname: "/" }}
                />
            ) : (
                <Component {...props} />
            )
            }
            {...rest}
        />
    )
}

export default AppRoutes
```

As you can see my interface is missing the component type. Not sure what to set it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to type component constructor you should use `import {ComponentType} from 'react'`.

So, if you want to build `Component` with props from `render` function, you should apply a constraint for `ComponentTypeProps`.

In other words, your `Component` should expect `Route['render']` type of argument.
In order to get type of `render` argument, you should use `ComponentProps` utility, which you can import from 'react'.

COnsider this example:

```js
type RenderProps = Parameters<NonNullable<ComponentProps<typeof Route>['render']>>[0]
```

Now you can use appropriate constraint:

```js
import React, { ComponentType, ComponentProps } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

interface AppProps {
  path: string,
  isPrivate: boolean,
  Component: ComponentType<RenderProps>
}

type RenderProps = Parameters<NonNullable<ComponentProps<typeof Route>['render']>>[0]

const AppRoutes = ({ Component, path, isPrivate, ...rest }: AppProps) => {

  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      render={props => <Component {...props} />}
      {...rest}
    />
  )
}

export default AppRoutes
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiTACoCeYS2hxZFAClBGAM5wC%20cAZuxBwA5FFQYRAbgBQoSLFyIIAVxhJeAoaPHoYAWnZqkUfQBMi0mXIon%206DQEEwYNh244ZcOGBQwAFgBccJwwUMAkAOaYXnDAnGzAAG5%20SMEARhAQADaoJDHejJDMMMFFpORUtEgAPMgkZiZuXAB8MjzWMNWI5I1QzdwAvHAsKFAoIEjqUJw1AHKkcyrZ2SjpuTXlJQM1XXQQ-MrGLQDaYr0mIgC6LacADFfWaKShcM5gCKrqQ3AAFHhbSrYXwBbDxRIpdTYAB0sPErx4wXeAwAlHBBi1cNZvOIYCooCQ-rFvHUvkhid4fH5-IMcCD-B1KZTxA0TLSwOwuOjMZsiMVKrhYdCOe4%20AB6FqMpmCuFIUJS7wS2Io9rWJAADwU8Ea9mW8Hen2MnCAA)